# calculate a new column using two related columns and the values of the 3rd column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

1. Im trying to calculate a new column using two related columns and the values of the 3rd column.
2. The problem is that I have first column (Alias) and it has redundant data and the second (Time Type) has related data to the cells of that of the first column (Alias).
3. Both the first and the second are text values.  The third however (Measure x) has number values. how can I make the calculation for such a table ?
4. I need to sum all the specific Alias activity for example `AIBRAHIM69` I need to sum the following (Day of Rest, Job, and On) then I need the Job value for  `AIBRAHIM69` to be divided by the sum of the time type of the  `AIBRAHIM69` (Day of Rest, Job, and On). Basically for `AIBRAHIM69` it will be `(7/19+7+5)`. so how can I calculate that ?

[Image of the table to be calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrKhH.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a measure something like

```
% to Total of Alias =
DIVIDE(
    SUM( 'Fact'[Measure X] ),
    CALCULATE( SUM( 'Fact'[Measure X] ), ALL( 'Fact'[Time Type] ) )
)
```

'Fact' will be replaced with the actual name of your table.